# Extra input with ajax in an existing form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, image-uploading

I have a big form and there are lots of inputs in it (about 15 inputs ).

I made it with normal submit type style with Laravel. I send my inputs to Controller to fetch and save them. But now I want to add extra multi-upload input(for some pictures) at the end of my form. 
I tried some nice-looking jquery plugins, but I couldn't achieve anything.

I send my inputs the normal way, but these jquery plugins are using ajax methods. I have one controller to save my inputs and when I write a new controller for ajax method, it saves into a new row in database . So my inputs and upload input don't match each other

What should I do ? 
Is there any solution for saving them in the same place or should I handle the entire form with ajax ? 
Or is it possible with a multistep form , in first form i can take normal inputs and in second form i can do ajax implementions.

Comment: Multiple files require multiple rows in the database, no matter how you twist or turn it. Either allow just one file to be saved and place that in that row, or What you could do is make an alternative table where you link your row in the database with the information to and save in there the images. Then it doesnt matter if an extra row is created, cause it receives the same rowid from your other database. You could do this then with a seperate ajax call or enter an extra statement in your controller.

Comment: i have multiple rows for my multiple file inputs but when i press submit , my 15 inputs goes a row and my multiple file inputs goes to a new another row in datebase, i cant bind them eachother